Oracle recursive child identification and merge with parent record in another table
I have 2 tables as follows:
parent_table



part_no
part_name
part_version
part_structure_type
part_structure_number
part_structure_version
part_structure_name




1001
pn1
7.1
com_part
1004
1.2
psn1


1002
pn2
8
com_part
1003
2.2
psn2


1003
pn3
9.1
com_part
1005
3.1
psn3



child_table



part_no
part_name
part_version
part_structure_type
part_structure_number
part_structure_version
part_structure_name




1001
pn1
7.1
com_part
1004
1.2
psn1


1004
pn2
9
com_part
1001
7.1
pn1


1003
pn3
9.1
com_mat
1004
9
pn2











1002
pn2
8
com_part
1003
2.2
psn2











1003
pn3
9.1
com_part
1005
3.1
psn3


1005
psn3
3.1
com_part
1006
9.1
pn3


1005
psn3
3.1
com_part
1007
10.1
pn4


1006
pn3
9.1
com_mat
1008
10.2
pn5


1007
pn4
10.1
com_mat
1009
11.3
pn6



output



part_no
part_name
part_version
part_structure_type
part_structure_number
part_structure_version
part_structure_name




1001
pn1
7.1
com_mat
1004
9
pn2


1003
pn3
9.1
com_mat
1008
10.2
pn5


1003
pn3
9.1
com_mat
1009
11.3
pn6



I need to pick each record from parent table and match part structure number and part structure version and part structure type with child table columns first..
If match found then,
I need to recursively iterate within child table records by comparing part number column data with part structure number column data and part version column data with part structure version column data until i get the rows containing part type as "com_mat" in child table.
If one or more child is found with part_type as com_mat, then i need to create  those many parent table picked records and update parent table part structure details  (part structure number and part structure version detail and names) with  child table rows having com_mat.
If there are no rows found in child table with "com_mat" for picked parent table record, then parent input can be skipped in the output..
Parent table contains 10 million records and need to find whether it got corresponding com_mat in child tables..
i tried to pick parent record one by one and loop those records within child table until i get all 'com_mat' records one by one but it takes huge amount of time for processing.
